# Save site as a template for Modern Team and Communication Site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-team-site

Is there a way to save site as a template if you are using Modern sites? I have followed some tutorials online where you use a script to enable scripting on site. I have also made sure if the Publishing features are disabled.

Is there a way to save modern sites as template. It was easy to do in Classic sites. Is this even an option for modern sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can save the modern site (modern team site and communication site) as the site template by visiting `/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx` page.

When you access `/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx` , access denied may occur. It occurs because the `denyaddandcustomizepages` of this site is `true`. [DenyAddAndCustomizePages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161394.aspx) determines whether the Add And Customize Pages right is denied on the site collection. By default, the right is denied on the modern site collection.

We need to [connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx) and set `denyaddandcustomizepages` of the site to `false`.

```
$adminUPN="<admin>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."

Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
set-sposite https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<communication/team> -denyaddandcustomizepages $false
```

Ten, you can access `/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx` page and save the site as template.

Comment: Is this recommended approach?

Comment: I don't think so it is a recommended approach but it did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

No, Modern Team/Communication sites do not support the save as template function -- in part because it was a bad idea in the first place, and because they have Publishing functionality enabled at all times with no ability to disable it.

The closest you can come to template-like functionality is via [Site Designs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview).

Comment: thank you @trevor. Let me go through the article and see if it helps me.

Comment: as far as my understanding goes, you need to create a site design of a site you plan to use as a template and then apply that design to other sites. Am i correct?

Is there a tool that builds this schema for you for a SP site?

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool that builds it for you. But you have it more or less correct. Site Designs can be extended via Azure Functions and Microsoft Flow, as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, go-to your sharepoint admin central and allow custom scripts in the settings section

[image]

Now, in the SharePoint online management shell, run the following powershell commands one after the other

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking

Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourname-admin.sharepoint.com/
```

This will prompt for user name and password

```
Set-SPOsite "https://yourname.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Once you run this, you should be able to save your site as template by visiting site settings and clicking on "Save site as Template"

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create site templates of team and communication sites and it actually works quite well.
http://webbrewers.com/modern-sharepoint-create-a-site-template-yes-communications-sites-too/